# Como podria obtener los dias Miercoles de cada semana en Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Al momento de emitir un documento o transaccion en mi sistema, necesito que tenga como fecha de emisión el miercoles de la semana actual, he buscado en google pero no consigo nada.

Lo mas cercano que pude encontrar es una funcion para obtener los Lunes de cada semana.

```
function getMonday(d) {
 d = new Date(d);
 var day = d.getDay(),
     diff = d.getDate() - day + (day == 0 ? -6:1); // adjust when day is sunday
 return new Date(d.setDate(diff));
}
```

Comment: Esta muy claro en MDN: "El valor devuelto por getDay() es un entero correspondiente al día de la semana; siendo 0 (Domingo) el primer día, 1 (Lunes) el segundo, etcétera. ". Si retorna 3 es miercoles

Comment: Esta muy claro en MDN: "El valor devuelto por getDay() es un entero correspondiente al día de la semana; siendo 0 (Domingo) el primer día, 1 (Lunes) el segundo, etcétera. ". Si retorna 3 es miercoles

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La solución es simple. Usando  `date.getDate() - date.getDay()` obtenemos el primer día de la semana, por tanto, sumándole 3, obtienes el miércoles de la semana. Simplemente modificas la fecha pasada por parámetros usando `setDate`.

La función quedaría:

```js
function getWednesday(date) {
    let delay = date.getDate() - date.getDay() + 3; 
    return new Date(date.setDate(delay));
}



// Pruebas 
const options = { weekday: 'long', year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' };

console.log(getWednesday(new Date(2018, 11, 1)).toLocaleDateString("es",options));
console.log(getWednesday(new Date(2018, 06, 11)).toLocaleDateString("es",options));
console.log(getWednesday(new Date()).toLocaleDateString("es",options));
```

Recuerda que el mes en el constructor de `Date` se pasa como un número de `0` a `11`.

Comment: Muchas gracias! Era lo que buscaba